# packaging program for win7 /32 / java8

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, runtime

I'm beginner with java Eclipse and i have to deploy a program (i recovered) on machines which are differents than the one i use to compile.

I have a dev PC : win 10 / 64 bits / java 10 / jdk & jre 8.271.
The program works fine under Eclipse environnement.

java version command returns :
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

Now I have to execute this program on win 7 / 32 bit / java 8(previously installed) machine.

I understood that 32/64b difference shouln't be a problem but mostly the java version.

The source code is compiled and packed with launch4j & inno setup to create an installer .
buildsetup.xml  uses kind of reference:

```
<property name="javac1.8.0_271" location="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/javac" />

<property name="versionJAVA4JAMIE" id="versionJAVA4JAMIE.prop" value="jre1.8.0_271" />
```

Java build path of Eclipse project contains JRE sytem library 1.8.0.271

that i don't know is if the installer contain java 10 for the target or if it is independant.

and also if java 10 is compatible with win7/32bit because i didn't see it on oracle website.

If not, does a java 10 unstallation and java 8 installation could be sufficient or have i to reinstall eclipse after java 8 ?

thank you

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You will need a 32 bit JRE to include in the launch4j for the 32 bit version - so you will have to create a separate 32 bit build. Eclipse can create compiled Java suitable for any release just by setting the "Compliance level" in the "Java Compiler" project properties.

Comment: ok for 32 bit jre.  could you tell me points i should clarify ?   How can check if the one i use is 32bit or not ? the fact that it is located in program file or program x86 is the distinctive criteria  ?

Comment: The java version output you showed says "64-Bit Server" - 64 bit. I think Java 8 was the last Java which even had a 32 bit version.

Comment: I'm be be lost in another post it was said "Compiled Java 'class' files run on both 32 and 64 bit, you don't need to compile them differently"     Could you confirm that the jre location in program file or program file x86 on dev machine distinguishes x64/x32 version ?           Jre in installer will install java 8 on target pc ?  So i just need to recover a 32 bit jre 1.8xxx and adding it to java build path ? also changing buid.xml line that refer to ? and what about jdk properties in xml file ?

Comment: I don't use Windows, so I don't know where it puts things.